# How to pass a function with a argument in a basic decorator using Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am reading about decorators and have learned quite a bit from [Simeons blog](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) I had success before when there was no arguments passed in the function like this: decorator(func). I think my issue is decorator(func(args)). I think my issue is func(args) is executing and passing its return value to the decorator instead of the function itself. How can I pass a function & argument in a decorator (example B) and not use the @decorator_name 'decoration' style (example A).

Edit: I would like example B to produce the same result as example A.

```
user_input = input("Type what you want:  ")

def camel_case(func):
   def _decorator(arg):
      s = ""
      words = arg.split()
      word_count = len(words)
      for i in range(word_count):
         if i >0:
            s += words[i].title()
         else:
            s += words[i].lower()
      return func(s)
   return _decorator
```

Example A: This works

```
@camel_case
def read(text):
   print("\n" + text" )

read(user_input)
```

Example B: This does not work

```
def read(text):
   print("\n" + text" )

camel_case(read(user_input))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What you should do: `camel_case(read)(user_input)`

Comment: Just edited the question. I would like both example B to produce the same result as example A.

Answer (score 2):

THe decorator takes a function:  `camel_case(read)`.  If you're trying to apply `camel_case` to the `read(user_input)` function, try this:

```
camel_case(read)(user_input)
```

`camel_case(read)` returns the decorated function, which you then call with `(user_input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Give the function to the decorator as an argument; the decorator returns a new function; then call this returned function with `user_input` as an argument:

```
camel_case(read)(user_input)
```